# Retrieve Gmail access_token

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I need to find the google **access_token** that is sent to the browser after user logs in to GMail. It should be somewhere among cookies or in a browser local storage.

The problem is that the 
`chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({url: authURL, interactive: true}, cb)`
wants from the user to choose the account again even when he is already logged in to GMail.

What I really want is something similar to Microsoft Outlook `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync` that allows to the logged user using Microsoft REST API without authenticating again.

**P.S.** GMail allows the user to be simultaneously logged in to multiple google accounts where each browser tab may show different active mailbox.

**P.P.S.** It looks like the well known issue that can be googled:
https://jindalsachin.wordpress.com/category/eathical-hacking/eathical-hacking-stuff/steal-gmail-cookiecookie-stealing-part-2/

I don't find the GX cookie in Dev console, may be it is not relevant anymore.
Instead of it the cookie that the most looks like the one is - 'COMPASS', it belongs to google domain, secured and http-only.

I tried to run this code in gmail context but still unsuccessfully:

```
let actualCode = '(' + function() {
        let access_token = '[COMPASS cookie]';
        window.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json', {
            credentials: "include"
        }).then(res => {
            return res.text().then(dt => ({text: dt, status: res.status}));
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });

        window.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + access_token, {
        }).then(res => {
            return res.text().then(dt => ({text: dt, status: res.status}));
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    } + ')();';

    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = actualCode;
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
```

I get `401:Invalid Credentials` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in this quick start and you will have an example of what you are looking for I think. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js - GAPI cannot be used in Chrome extension. It is known issue.

Comment: this might be useful? otherwise I've missed the mark completely. 
When calling getAuthToken, you can pass a flag ('interactive': false) -> silent mode .

Comment: That is the problem. In order to use {'interactive': false} I need to be logged in with this script. It doesn't recognize the user that is already logged in to GMail.